# I have s str variable containing list of float values, all i want to convert into numpy array with type float64 in python

Tags: python, numpy

```
s = "[-3.34 -0.34]"
```

s type is str and its size is 1

what is want is to convert this str into numpy float64 array into like this

```
s = [-3.34 -0.34]
```

Comment: Generally for these problems, looking at a specific string is not enough information. For example, would a rule of drop the first, last, and separate at the space (which is trivial to write and works here) always work?

Comment: That looks like the `str` display of an array.  That's not intended for reconstructing the array.  You need to make it into a list of strings that individually can be converted to float.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.array(list(map(float, s[1:-1].split())))
```

`s[1:-1]` will print out everything between the brackets as a string.
`.split()` will split the string at the spaces into a list of 2 strings.
`map()` will convert the strings into floats.
`list()` will convert the map object into a list.
`np.array()` will convert the list into a numpy array.

```
print(s[1:-1].split())
# "-3.34 -0.34"
print(map(float, s[1:-1].split()))
# <map object at 0x108146128>
print(list(map(float, s[1:-1].split())))
# [-3.34, -0.34]
print(np.array(list(map(float, s[1:-1].split()))))
# [-3.34 -0.34]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for because there is no comma is your expression but, assuming that you just want to create an array, you can do this :

```
expr = "[-3.34, -0.34]"
s = eval(expr)
```